# fatal error condition: SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation error for my code when the test is run. What causes this?

Tags: c++, nodes, valgrind

Triple rotate is supposed to rotate 3 Nodes together so, middle to front, front to back, and back to the middle, and if length %3 isn't 0 the remaining one or two do not get rotated.

> 123456 -> 231564.

> 1234567 ->2315647.

This happens when I run Valgrind, and no memory leaks are shown.
The error occurs when tests use my tripleRotate function in Lists.

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::tripleRotate() {
  // @todo Graded in MP3.1
  if (length_ < 3) {
    return;
  }
  ListNode* curr = head_;
  int i = 0;
  ListNode* one;
  ListNode* two;
  ListNode* three;
  while (curr != NULL) {
    one = curr;
    two = curr->next;
    three = curr->next->next;
    one = two;
    two = three;
    three = curr;
    if (i == 0) {
      head_ = one;
      i++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    if (curr == NULL && length_ % 3 == 0) {
      tail_ = three;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the line from tests

```
TEST_CASE("List::triplerotate simple", "[weight=10][part=1][valgrind]") {
    List<int> list;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        list.insertBack(i);

    list.tripleRotate();

    stringstream s;

    list.print(s);

    REQUIRE("< 2 3 1 5 6 4 >" == s.str());
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  This means that you post all of the code that allows anyone to compile the code, run the program, and thus duplicate the issue.

Comment: How is `List` defined. I suspect the `SIGSEV` occurs when you access `curr->next->next` without checking for a null pointer of `curr->next`

Comment: `two = curr->next; three = curr->next->next;` does not check if `two` has been set to `nullptr`.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! adding an if statement which breaks the loop if curr->next is NULL seems to have solved the problem